# Ruby on Rails group_by is not grouping in the correct order using DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

First I get a collection of channels from my scope

`Channel.not_archived.map { |c| channels << c }`

Then I sort those by the `start_time` attribute:

`channels.sort! { |a, b| a.start_time <=> b.start_time }`

Then I want to group them by their start times.  So channels that start at 8:00am will be grouped together.  So I use the `group_by` method:

`@grouped_channels = @channels.group_by { |c| time_with_offset(c).strftime("%I:%M %P") }`

the time_with_offset method:

```
  # Returns time with offset
  def time_with_offset(channel)
    user = current_user.time_zone.to_i
    organization = channel.organization.time_zone.to_i
    time_offset = organization -= user

    channel.start_time - time_offset.hours
  end
```

And I get back all of my records in the correct group.  The issue i'm having is that the groups are not in order.  So the group of 8:00am should be before the group of 9:00am.  It's just in weird random order now.  Can anyone help me get these in correct order?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to reorder the key-value pairs of any hash `h` in key order given by an array `keys`, which contains all the keys in the desired order, write

```
(keys.zip(h.values_at(*keys))).to_h
```

For Ruby versions prior to 2.0, write

```
Hash[keys.zip(h.values_at(*keys))]
```

For example,

```
h = { b: 1, d: 2, a: 3, c: 4 }
  #=> {:b=>1, :d=>2, :a=>3, :c=>4}
keys = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

(keys.zip(h.values_at(*keys))).to_h
  #=> {:a=>3, :b=>1, :c=>4, :d=>2}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = h.values_at(*keys)
  #=> same as h.values_at(:a, :b, :c, :d)
  #=> [3, 1, 4, 2]

b = keys.zip(a)
  # => [[:a, 3], [:b, 1], [:c, 4], [:d, 2]] 
b.to_h
  #=> {:a=>3, :b=>1, :c=>4, :d=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are sorting by one time, then you are grouping by a different time. I expect this explains your undesired order.

Sort by the offset time.

```
channels.sort_by { |c| time_with_offset(c) }.group_by { |c| time_with_offset(c).strftime("%I:%M %P") }
```